# Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.get_RetryMode() deadlock

Tags: aws-sdk-net

I'm running a .net Framework ASP.NET WebApi application on Elastic Beanstalk and it occasionally becomes unresponsive.

We've got some process dumps of w3wp.exe and the blocking thread gets stuck on a call to `Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.get_RetryMode()`. This causes a deadlock as it doesn't release a lock obtained in `Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Logger.GetLogger`. Subsequent calls get blocked in `GetLogger()` waiting for the lock to be released which never happens.

Any idea why `Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.get_RetryMode()` doesn't return?

**Blocking Call Stack**

```
Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.get_RetryMode()+2f
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.BuildRuntimePipeline()+1cd
AWS.Logger.Core.AWSLoggerCore..ctor(AWS.Logger.AWSLoggerConfig, System.String)+1b0
AWS.Logger.Log4net.AWSAppender.ActivateOptions()+131
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseAppender(System.Xml.XmlElement)+47b
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.FindAppenderByReference(System.Xml.XmlElement)+1dc
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseChildrenOfLoggerElement(System.Xml.XmlElement, log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger, Boolean)+110
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.ParseRoot(System.Xml.XmlElement)+5f
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.Configure(System.Xml.XmlElement)+554
log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.XmlRepositoryConfigure(System.Xml.XmlElement)+c9
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.InternalConfigure(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository, System.IO.Stream)+2ad
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.InternalConfigure(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository, System.IO.FileInfo)+18f
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository, System.Uri)+77
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.ConfigureRepository(System.Reflection.Assembly, log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository)+2d1
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.CreateRepository(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Type, System.String, Boolean)+2bf
log4net.Core.DefaultRepositorySelector.GetRepository(System.Reflection.Assembly)+3e
log4net.Core.LoggerManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Type)+45
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
[[HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ] (System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod)] System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])+84
mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)+92
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.InternalLog4netLogger..ctor(System.Type)+d8
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Logger..ctor(System.Type)+5f
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Logger.GetLogger(System.Type)+af
Amazon.Runtime.AppConfigAWSCredentials..ctor()+33
Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory+<>c.b__10_0()+1f
Amazon.Runtime.FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials(Boolean)+c7
Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient..ctor(Amazon.RegionEndpoint)+3b
// UserCode new Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(region)
```

**Blocked Call Stack**

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Logger.GetLogger(System.Type)+68
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient..ctor(Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials, Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig)+8d
// UserCode new Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(region)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the dead lock was caused by fallback process.

```
Aws Appender 
-> obtain Logger 
-> Would release Logger after setting up finish 
-> setting up is missing some info , call fallback to figure out 
-> failed connection, get_RetryMode() 
-> trying to obtain Logger (dead lock generated)
```

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense mostly except for the error was sporadic. Sometimes it worked fine including writing logs to Cloudwatch with the same configuration. Our workaround was to log to the local file system and cloudwatch agent to ship the logs to Cloudwatch in a separate process.